# Deleting specific text in several columns in an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I have several columns with several cells. Some of them contain the letter "R". I want to change all cells across all columns that contain the word "R" to be replaced with a blank. Normally I would just do a REPLACE all for the letter "R" with a blank, but this will mess up other columns that might have a word like "Road" in it. So, how do I replace all R's, but ONLY if the cell ONLY contains R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok. here is what you do.

- select all the cells on your sheet
- then hit ctrl+F
- select the 'replace' tab
- click on options
- check 'match case'
- check 'match entire cell contents'
- in 'find what'- R
- in 'replace with'- whatever you want
- click 'replace all'

Answer (score 1):

In "Find and Replace", expand the "Options" section and check the "Match entire cell contents" option.

Then when you perform your replace, words containing 'R' won't be affected.  You should also check the "Match Case" option if you want to match 'R' but not 'r'.